# Use tabs to switch <section> background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-studio

What I'm trying to do is have the tabs change the background image shown in the section.

Similar to this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/r6r7U/12/

But I can't get that method to work for me. How can I change an image with each tab? Ex - tab 1 shows background1, tab2 shows background2, etc.

There is a working example of what I mean on this website - https://www.vidyard.com/

```css
.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.page-section.page-section-center {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.page-section.page-section-lg {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.page-section.page-section-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0px transparent solid !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs a {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2db2e9 !important;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  border-bottom: 0px transparent solid !important;
  color: #32404E;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  color: #50667d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="page-section page-section-xlg page-section-center page-section-white help-nav-tabs page-section-no-bd">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="help-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#how-ot-maintenance" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Maintenance
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#how-ot-crm" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Sales &amp; Marketing
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#how-ot-projects" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Project Management
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content wrap wrap-bt wrap-bt-lg">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="how-ot-maintenance">
          <h2>Control Costs</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="how-ot-crm">
          <h2>Customer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="how-ot-projects">
          <h2>Take</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What javascript have you tried?

Comment: @JoshSanger I've tried using the Javascript from the JSFiddle - but like I mentioned I can't get that to work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap requires jQuery. Once you add jQuery you can see the demo works. I have added separate background colors so you can see the change better. Simple replace the background color with and image.

```css
/* START OF EDIT */

* {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
#main {
  transition: background 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}
.tab-background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ff9000 no-repeat center center / cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  position: absolute;
}
li.active .tab-background {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* END OF EDIT */

.page-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.page-section.page-section-center {
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.page-section.page-section-lg {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.page-section.page-section-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs > li.active > a {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0px transparent solid !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs a {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2db2e9 !important;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
  border-bottom: 0px transparent solid !important;
  color: #32404E;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: color ease 0.3s;
  transition: color ease 0.3s;
}
.help-nav-tabs .nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: 0px !important;
  color: #50667d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="main" class="page-section page-section-xlg page-section-center page-section-white help-nav-tabs page-section-no-bd">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="help-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <div class="tab-background" style="background-image: url(http://www.animalfactguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/sloth4_full.jpg);"></div>
          <a href="#how-ot-maintenance" data-background-color="white" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Maintenance
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <div class="tab-background" style="background-image: url(http://www.euclidlibrary.org/images/tickle-your-brain/slotheatingleaf.jpg?sfvrsn=0);"></div>
          <a href="#how-ot-crm" data-toggle="tab" data-background-color="rebeccapurple" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Sales &amp; Marketing
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <div class="tab-background" style="background-image: url(http://kids.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/kids/photos/animals/Mammals/Q-Z/sloth-beach-upside-down.jpg.adapt.945.1.jpg);"></div>
          <a href="#how-ot-projects" data-toggle="tab" data-background-color="indianred" aria-expanded="true" data-no-scroll>
                        Project Management
                    </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content wrap wrap-bt wrap-bt-lg">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="how-ot-maintenance">
          <h2>Control Costs</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="how-ot-crm">
          <h2>Customer</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="how-ot-projects">
          <h2>Take</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes that works for changing the color of the tab content. I want to change the entire <section> background. 

You can see in the example I left.

Comment: Made an edit to the code. Essentially, store the color (or image) in a data attribute. Bootstrap has the event `shown.bs.tab` that fires when a tab is changed. When that event fires, grab the color (or image) and change the css of the parent `#main`

Comment: Ok that looks better thanks.
And if images are being used? what changes?

Comment: background-image instead of background and include the url in the data attribute. If you want it to fade nicely it may have to be a few elements that you toggle back and forth.

Comment: I can't get that working on my end. Any way you can edit your answer to show it working?

Comment: Done. I removed the javascript and went with a CSS only solution. Basically, since bootstrap adds a class of `.active` to the active `<li>`you can use that to switch images. I placed an image in each of the `<li>` elements and put a background image on those with a position of absolute. I made the parent container `#main` relative so the background image will fill the space. If this works for you please accept the answer :)

Comment: Ok i see it working - great! What would cause mine to only affect the tabs? I used your exact mark up and it's only applying to the tabs. Otherwise this looks perfect for what i am trying to get!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133102/discussion-between-josh-sanger-and-becca).